# How to rename colnames when getting data from JSON inR

Tags: r

I have a dataset which I am getting from JSON and when I get it during the first step of cleaning it the colnames are following:

```
[1] "list(\"col\")"              "list(\"col1\")"        "list(\"col2\")"         "list(\"col3\")"          "list(\"col4\")"
```

As of now, I am renaming these liked

```
colnames(df) <- c("col","col1","col2","col3","col4")
```

But I don't know if I get any other columns in my data. So how would I about renaming them from list and not hardcoding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear whether the `list` prefix is based on pre-processsing issue or not.  But, one way to clean up after creating it is look for specific elements with prefix `list` (`grep`) and extract the words from the column names with `sub`, update the column names by assigning the extracted words

```
i1 <- grep("^list", names(df))
names(df)[i1] <- sub('^list\\("([^"]+)".*', "\\1", names(df)[i1])
```

Here the regex is matching the 'list' at the start (`^`) of the string, followed by the literal `(` (escaped as it has special meaning), followed by the quote and then capture the characters that are not quote (`[^"]`) as a group (`(...)`), in the replacement, specify the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

---

In `tidyverse`, we can use `rename_at`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   rename_at(vars(starts_with('list')), ~ 
            str_replace(., 'list\\("([^"]+)".*', '\\1'))
```